# How to re-compile the apk extracted content into a apk file after making changes to it?

Tags: android, apk

How to re-compile the apk extracted content into a `.apk` file after making changes to it. I have extracted it using [Java decompiler online](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) and made changes to res/values. Now I want to put it back together as installable `.apk` file.

Answer (score 0):

Since an .apk is a zipped file, you can just rename it from .apk to .zip, replace the values.xml and revert to .apk. Keep in mind that this will break the signature and you should always recompile when you make any changes

Comment: And how do I recompile that is my query

Comment: Generate new signed .apk on Android Studio